# Possibility to keep media folder in sync for products

Tags: magento-1.9

We are migrating our store to Magento, in the old system, we keep in sync with rsync the images and other binary files, so that whenever there is a new media file or binary file, we don't need to upload via web.

I have added products via SOAP API to Magento, images are added to database thanks to Magento internals, but is it possible to have Magento be notified whenever there is an update in media files for this product? Of course i understand that a module is required to add this behaviour.